# Android - Progress Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm a having a problem. I want to make a progress dialog while my app download some news from a feed.
This is my code at the moment:

```
public class NyhedActivity extends Activity {
    String streamTitle = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nyheder);

        TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

           try {
       URL rssUrl = new URL("http://rss.tv2sport.dk/rss/*/*/*/248/*/*");
       SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
       XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
       RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
       myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
       InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
       myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

       result.setText(streamTitle);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       result.setText("Cannot connect RSS!");
      } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       result.setText("Cannot connect RSS!");
      } catch (SAXException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       result.setText("Cannot connect RSS!");
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       result.setText("Cannot connect RSS!");
      }


       }

       private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler
       {
        final int stateUnknown = 0;
        final int stateTitle = 1;
        int state = stateUnknown;

        int numberOfTitle = 0;
        String strTitle = "";
        String strElement = "";

      @Override
      public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       strTitle = "Nyheder fra ";
      }

      @Override
      public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       strTitle += "";
       streamTitle = "" + strTitle;
      }

      @Override
      public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
       {
        state = stateTitle;
        strElement = "";
        numberOfTitle++;
       }
       else
       {
        state = stateUnknown;
       }
      }

      @Override
      public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
       {
        strTitle += strElement + "\n"+"\n";
       }
       state = stateUnknown;
      }

      @Override
      public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       String strCharacters = new String(ch, start, length);
       if (state == stateTitle)
       {
        strElement += strCharacters;
       }
      }
    }

}
```

I can't figure out how to use the progress dialog. Is it possible for anyone to show my where to define the progressdialog and least but not most how to implement it.
I've looked a lot of places, but everyone seems to do it different ways, and I can't get any of them to work :(

I've even tried to make a fake one which runs on sleep, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{

final static int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 1;

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
   switch(id){
   case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
      dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
      dialog.setMessage("Whatever you want to tell them.");
      dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
      dialog.setCancelable(true); // if you want people to be able to cancel the download
      dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
         @Override
         public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
         {
             **** cleanup.  Not needed if not cancelable ****
         }});
      return dialog;
   default:
      return null;
   }
}
```

When you want it to appear, you can do `showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG)` and when you want it to go away you can do `dialog.dismiss()`.

Comment: I've tried that way. I can't figure out where to start the ProgressDialog in my code to get it to work.
And when i get it to start, I can't dismiss it.
I think I maybe placing things in the wrong scope :/

Comment: Instead of creating the reference in the method, it should be global to the class.  I'll update it.  To start the progress, call `showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG)` at the time you want to start it.  Then call `dialog.dismiss()` to remove it.  I'll make some edits.

Comment: I got it to start a couple of times, but then it can't use the dismiss even though i make the progress dialog in the global class.
But I'm very new to Java, and don't fully understand all the rules.
Looking forward to se the solution, ass i've used almost 3 hours doing try and error :)

Comment: Your app will crash if you call anything on `dialog` before you create the object at `dialog = new ProgressDialog(this)`.  You can ensure that doesn't happen by putting that line in  `onCreate()`. Other than that, if the window doesn't go away, then you're not calling `dialog.dismiss()` even if you think you are.

Comment: I can't paste the above code into my project when i create my class.
I got a syntax error, delete these token on the
(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
          @Override
          public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
          {
              **** cleanup.  Not needed if not cancelable ****
          }});

I can't figure out, what i'm doing wrong. Feeling like a complete retard for not being able to do such an easy thing, even though I've  i completed much bigger task before.

Comment: My code was not complete (plus I had a few typos that I fixed).  The stars were a message for you and were for code.

Comment: What I don't understand is where to place it in my code. I've tried everything.

final static int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 1;
ProgressDialog dialog;

Should be before my Oncreate, that I understand? The rest I can't figure out where to put.

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  Some people put private variables at the top of the class or at the bottom.  In Java, it doesn't matter.  `onCreateDialog()` overrides a method in `Activity` so you have to put that method somewhere in the class.  Again, there are conventions, but it Java will compile no matter where you put it.

Comment: Okay, I think i got it working now, but it seems my process is loading to fast for the progress dialog to show. Is that possible?

Because if I remove my dismiss it shows, but if it's there it don't show. 
Or is that caused by wrong placement?

Comment: It could be caused by either.  If you put it in the onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask, then that's the best place for it because it means whatever your operation was doing was done.  If you want to test it, in the doInBackground() method, but Thread.sleep(3000); to make it sleep for three seconds.  Your dialog box should be up when that happens.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for you patience. Now i understand how it works. I won't take more of your time.

Have a really nice weekend sir!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do *any* long-running stuff like network IO in the UI thread (that's what calls your `onCreate()`), Android will force close your app. Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead, check out the linked javadoc for an example.

- Create and show your progress dialog in `onPreExecute()` and keep a reference to it in a field
- Update progress by calling `publishProgress()` from your `doInBackground()` and handle that in `onProgressUpdate()`, e.g. like the example linked above
- Close your progress dialog and update your UI (text fields, etc.) in `onPostExecute()`

To create the dialog in `onPreExecute()`, pass a `Context` to your `AsyncTask` constructor, e.g. your activity `this` and store it in a field.

If you want your data to survive orientation changes or persist across activity restarts, let your `AsyncTask` write your parsed data into a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and then display it only the database contents in your activity.

---

As for the actual "showing a progress dialog" part, use one of its static factory methods `show(...)`:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
    this, // a context, e.g. your activity
    "Downloading...", // title
    "Downloading RSS feed.", // message
);
```

This will create and show a dialog in one step.

Comment: Also this ^^^^^^.  You can do `showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG)` in the `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it on `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Yes, using a managed dialog like DeeV suggested would work. Try both approaches :)

Comment: Thanks. I read something about it, but I thought there was a "more" light way to do it. Since the above code was working, I thought it was okay to do it that way. But I will try to do things in Async task instead. Thanx for the sugestion :)